# What are the order of kill taunts, from fastest to slowest?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Question says it all.  I'm trying to create a montage of kill taunts.  What are the fastest kill taunts, and to which class do they belong?

Comment: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Taunts#Special_taunts seems to list durations accurate only to the nearest second, although the next section is accurate to the nearest 1/10 of a second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heavys Showdown using Fists. It's the fastest. Can hit from a range towards where you aim. 3 seconds duration of whole taunt, but hit is around 2-2.5 second.

Pyros Hadouken using secondary weapons. Can destroy buildings, slightly slower than Showdown. 3 second duration hit during end of taunt.

Snipers Skewer using huntsman. It's the easiest to hit, the stun effect hits after about a second, target then will be killed. 4 second duration. Kill is during pullback and end of taunt.

For a full list:
http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Taunts

Comment: The Sniper's Huntsman taunt is also the only thing in the game (AFAIK) that can affect an Ubered medic. If you can manage to stab-stab-stab him while he's ubered he *will* be stunned. He'll remain invulnerable but won't be able to move. His Uber target will remain invulnerable too.

Comment: @Dan C: Nope, any action that stuns can still stun a Medic or his patient while ÜberCharged, this also includes an enemy Medic's Übersaw taunt, or a Sandman baseball.

Comment: Hey, what about the Spy's Fencing taunt? Or Soldier's Equalizer taunt? Or Scout's Sandman taunt? ((I think that's in order of fasteset to slowest, but not sure))

Comment: They are all listed in the full list, I just listed the fastest ones.